# how to convert textfile to a json format in python

Tags: python

How can I get the first format to take the form of the second

first format

```
{"created_at": "2020-12-05 20:49:30 Pacific Standard Time", "quote_url": "", "video": 0, "thumbnail": "", "near": "", "geo": "", "source": "", "user_rt_id": "", "user_rt": "", "retweet_id": "", "reply_to": [], "retweet_date": "", "translate": "", "trans_src": "", "trans_dest": ""}
{"created_at": "2020-12-05 20:48:24 Pacific Standard Time", "quote_url": "", "video": 0, "thumbnail": "", "near": "", "geo": "", "source": "", "user_rt_id": "", "user_rt": "", "retweet_id": "", "reply_to": [], "retweet_date": "", "translate": "", "trans_src": "", "trans_dest": ""}
{"created_at": "2020-12-05 20:47:23 Pacific Standard Time", "quote_url": "", "video": 0, "thumbnail": "", "near": "", "geo": "", "source": "", "user_rt_id": "", "user_rt": "", "retweet_id": "", "reply_to": [], "retweet_date": "", "translate": "", "trans_src": "", "trans_dest": ""}
{"created_at": "2020-12-05 20:46:46 Pacific Standard Time", "quote_url": "", "video": 0, "thumbnail": "", "near": "", "geo": "", "source": "", "user_rt_id": "", "user_rt": "", "retweet_id": "", "reply_to": [], "retweet_date": "", "translate": "", "trans_src": "", "trans_dest": ""}
```

Target - sencond format

```
{"data":[{"created_at": "2020-12-05 20:49:30 Pacific Standard Time", "quote_url": "", "video": 0, "thumbnail": "", "near": "", "geo": "", "source": "", "user_rt_id": "", "user_rt": "", "retweet_id": "", "reply_to": [], "retweet_date": "", "translate": "", "trans_src": "", "trans_dest": ""},
{"created_at": "2020-12-05 20:48:24 Pacific Standard Time", "quote_url": "", "video": 0, "thumbnail": "", "near": "", "geo": "", "source": "", "user_rt_id": "", "user_rt": "", "retweet_id": "", "reply_to": [], "retweet_date": "", "translate": "", "trans_src": "", "trans_dest": ""},
{"created_at": "2020-12-05 20:47:23 Pacific Standard Time", "quote_url": "", "video": 0, "thumbnail": "", "near": "", "geo": "", "source": "", "user_rt_id": "", "user_rt": "", "retweet_id": "", "reply_to": [], "retweet_date": "", "translate": "", "trans_src": "", "trans_dest": ""},
{"created_at": "2020-12-05 20:46:46 Pacific Standard Time", "quote_url": "", "video": 0, "thumbnail": "", "near": "", "geo": "", "source": "", "user_rt_id": "", "user_rt": "", "retweet_id": "", "reply_to": [], "retweet_date": "", "translate": "", "trans_src": "", "trans_dest": ""}]}
```

Comment: Please be more specific what exactly you need help with. Reading a file? Reading a file line by line? Creating a list? Creating a dict? Writing a file? Please also include the code you've written so far in your question.

Comment: Technically, the first file is already in jsonlines format

Comment: Write exactly the second format in Python and the output of the Jason file, please

Comment: I will give you a small hint: Let's call your current file's lines `x0`, `x1`... Then your new output is `{"data": [x0, x1, x2, x3]}`. I'm sure you can do it from here or at least try and ask a specific question about what you're struggling with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the files are as you mentioned, each line already appears to be valid JSON.

You can simply read the file, prepend the first bit and append commas / the last bit.

```py
lines = ['{"data":[{']  # get that prefix ready
with open("/path/to/fileA", "r") as f:
    lines += [x.rstrip('\n') + ",\n" for x in f.readlines()]  # add the lines with commas
lines[-1] = lines[-1][:-2] + "]}"
with open("/path/to/fileB", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Of course, there are arguably better ways to do this, using the standard `json` library, but based on your question, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: Why are you just suggesting `json` as a note? That should be the way to do it instead of constructing a weird string

Comment: @Tomerikoo Because there's little reason to use the `json` library (which would parse and format output unnecessarily) when the modification is this simple. It isn't like the OP wants the data flattened / zipped / some other modification done to it. They only asked for simple prefix/suffix transformation.

Based off the question as it is posed, they appear to be a beginner (at Python or programming), so my goal was to keep it as simple as possible, not introducing libraries and parsing and transforming data in a complex manner.

Comment: New users should be exposed to new libraries, not deprived of them because they are beginners... Second, in my opinion, using the built-in `json` will be easier and more readable, even for a beginner, but that might be subjective

Comment: thank you. I just started with the Python programming language and my novice answered your code correctly.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Users should be exposed to new libs, once they are at the point of actually getting more experience in the language. I could use `json.loads` in a loop, spit it back out, etc. Then I'd have to go into subtleties about key order depending on the version of python used, the fix, data not being written out exactly as it was read in (depending on a number of variables I can't foresee). All the while probably overwhelming OP. Or I could keep it to simple text manipulation, as I did. Don't start JS with React, C++ with boost, C with function pointers. My experience- start simple, builtin.